# T4 Generate ASP.NET WebForm UI

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, code-generation, t4

I'm staring to learn T4 .
I want to create a framework for my self that enable me to generate DAL and UI.
Like Code generator softwares that maps Codes and User Interface from database .
i don't have any question about generating data access layer.
my challenge is to generate UI ( asp.net controls and HTML).
is there any sample exist with T4?
what are your suggestions about this Code Generator that i want create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try my post here: [T4 Templates for ASP.NET Web Form CRUD Application](http://nampark.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/t4-templates-for-asp-net-web-form/).

I put a very basic code snippet generating templates for an aspx page (DetailsView and GridView for CRUD), ObjectDataSource methods for CRUD operations in VB, and SQL stored procedures matching with them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch)? I feel your search ends at [Microsoft LightSwitch](http://pradeepgururani.blogspot.com/2011/03/overview-of-microsoft-visual-studio.html).

LightSwitch is able to generate UI for you. All you need to do is tell it to pull the data from one of the logical ends it is able to understand. As of now it is letting you talk to 1) WCF RIA services, 2) to Sharepoint through WCF data services and you can also connect LightSwitch presentation layer to Entity Framework.

Besides this you get amazing capability to customize your UI. LightSwitch UI is basically Silverlight 4 based UI which can be hosted out of browser or on a web server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does LightSwitch Able To Generate UI for ASP.net ?

Comment: It generates UI in Silverlight 4.0, but not in ASP.Net. Give it a shot, I hope you will be happy.

Comment: Thank You :) i will try it , but still i have to Use ASP.NET (html) as Presentation Layer.